# How to get a toddler off the bottle?

Tags: toddler, bottle-feeding, weaning

I’ve been trying to get my 18-month-old daughter off the bottle. I  bought  a few cups I think she might like: A hard top sippy cup n a soft sippy cup.
She will take either one during the day, but  when it’s naptime or bedtime, she freaks out and wants the bottle.

I have 2 other kids, 12 and 10. And I have no idea how I got them off the bottle. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

We had exactly the same problem, at almost the same age.

The one thing that really helped us was by getting a completely different cup for bed time unlike any of her other day time cups.

In our case this was a munchkin 360 cup with no handles and a different colour. (all her other cups have handles).

I think the novelty of a completely different new cup and the no handles helped as similar to a bottle.

Another suggestion that worked when she woke overnight, (which was way more difficult than before bed) was that we only put water in her bottle but milk in her cup, she wanted the milk so eventually gave up on the bottle as she didn't like the water.